# organize 5 subjects in 6 periods

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

> There are 6 periods in each working day of a school. In how many ways
> can one organize 5 subjects such that each subject is allowed at least
> one period? Is the answer 1800 or 3600 ?

I have asked this question before ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307879/6-periods-and-5-subjects)) in this site itself to understand the right answer - 3600 or 1800?

@Ross Millikan has given me a convincing answer and explained idea of overcounting and why 3600 is wrong. Posting it again here to assert the answer is 1800 and not 3600, mainly because almost all websites give 3600 as answer and only one website gives answer as 1800. Listing the websites for reference

> (1) Ans is 3600 see([m4maths.com](http://www.m4maths.com/10854-if-there-are-Six-periods-in-each-working-day-of-a-school-In-how-many-ways-can-one-arrange-5.html))
>
> (2) Ans is 3600 see question 15 in ([campusgate.co.in](http://www.campusgate.co.in/2012/10/tcs-latest-pattern-questions-with_16.html))
>
> (3) Ans is 3600 - see 8th question in
> ([alaudeenali.blogspot.in](http://alaudeenali.blogspot.in/2013/11/problems-on-permutauions-and.html))
>
> (4) Ans is 3600 - see example 5 in
> ([gmatclub.com](http://gmatclub.com/forum/permutations-and-combinations-simplified-150835.html))
>
> These sites as well as almost all reputed sites
> give the answer as 3600.
>
> But answer is 1800 according to [careerbless.com](http://localhost/aptitude/qa/discuss/permutations_combinations/discussion00000024322.php)

Sorry for asking the question again. Please tell me which is the right answer. 1800 or 3600. Since I am preparing for my exams, I don't want to be in the wrong path and hence clarifying.

Comment: The reasoning behind 3600 is certainly wrong. It counts every possibility twice. It would only make sense if the repeated subject were distinguished somehow (for example, suppose all the courses are offered in English, but the repeated course is offered in English and in French).

Comment: Now we know which websites are unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote for $1800$.  My argument:  Exactly one of the subjects will be repeated.  There are $5$ ways to select the double.  We then must arrange the letters $AABCDE$ in the $6$ slots.  There are $\binom 62$ ways to place the $A's$ and then $4!$ ways to position $BCDE$ in the remaining slots.  Thus:  $$5\times \binom 62\times 4!=1800$$

Comment: You assume that AA has to come together. The question does not say that. The answer is 3600

Comment: @user2277550  No I don't.  The $A's$ can occupy any $2$ slots, hence the $\binom 62$.

Comment: @user2277550, he does not assume that AA has to come together. He selected any two places for A (6C2)

Comment: The way I read the problem, I did not assume all 6 periods had to be filled.  I think the question is worded ambiguously regarding this. If you went with the alternate interpretation, there would be another 6! possibilities for a total of 2520.

Comment: @user1735179  If memory serves, the first time I read the problem I assumed that the case you mention was the only case to consider (whence the answer would be $6!=720$).  But every single linked solution to the problem, whether they get $1800$ or $3600$, considers only the pattern $AABCDE$  so I just counted those.

Answer (score 5):

I will give another approach that may appeal.

Think of it as permutations of an alphabet string of subjects, e.g. $AABCDE$ to fill $6$ periods.

By the permutation formula, this yields $6!/2! = 360$ ways

But the "double" subject can be chosen in $5$ ways, thus ans = $5\cdot360 = \boxed{1800}$

Comment: AABCDE . What about ABBCDE and its arrangements?

Comment: ok, got it. It takes care of all